# Sqldf: Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : near "over": syntax error in R

Tags: r, data.table, rodbc, sqldf

Example of my data

```
mydata=structure(list(generated_id = c(1003477323030100, 1003477323030100, 
1003477323030100, 1003477323030100, 1003477323030100, 1003477323030100, 
1003477323030100, 1003477323030100, 1003477323030100, 1003477323030100, 
1003477323030100, 1003477323030100, 1003477323030100, 1003477323030100, 
1003477323030100, 1003477323030100, 1003477323030100), campaign_id.x = c(23843069854050700, 
23843069854050700, 23843069854050700, 23843069854050700, 23843069854050700, 
23843069854050700, 23843069854050700, 23843069854050700, 23843069854050700, 
23843069854050700, 23843069854050700, 23843069854050700, 23843069854050700, 
23843069854050700, 23843069854050700, 23843069854050700, 23843069854050700
), campaign_id.y = c(23843069854050700, 23843069854050700, 23843069854050700, 
23843069854050700, 23843069854050700, 23843069854050700, 23843069854050700, 
23843069854050700, 23843069854050700, 23843069854050700, 23843069854050700, 
23843069854050700, 23843069854050700, 23843069854050700, 23843069854050700, 
23843069854050700, 23843069854050700), spent = c(73.5, 73.5, 
73.5, 73.5, 73.5, 73.5, 73.5, 73.5, 73.5, 73.5, 73.5, 29.74, 
29.74, 29.74, 29.74, 29.74, 29.74), date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("04.10.2018", 
"26.09.2018"), class = "factor"), realpurchase_cash = c(1.49, 
1.49, 1.49, 1.49, 1.49, 1.49, 1.49, 1.49, 1.49, 1.49, 1.49, 1.49, 
1.49, 1.49, 1.49, 1.49, 1.49), utc_time.y = structure(c(5L, 8L, 
2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 9L, 10L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("01.10.2018 22:26", 
"05.10.2018 22:34", "05.10.2018 22:35", "06.10.2018 13:43", "07.10.2018 15:55", 
"30.09.2018 11:22", "30.09.2018 11:23", "30.09.2018 12:00", "30.09.2018 12:23", 
"30.09.2018 18:12"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("generated_id", 
"campaign_id.x", "campaign_id.y", "spent", "date", "realpurchase_cash", 
"utc_time.y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -17L))
```

I need to restructure as follows:

> if for the group `generated_id +capmaing_id.x+campaing_id.y` the aggregated up to 90 days value of `realpurchase_cash` is greater than the aggregated up to 90 days value of spent, then the whole group is assign to 1, otherwise 0.
>   To aggregate spent by sum by months , it is column date, but
>   to aggregate `realpurchase_cash` by sum by months , it is column `utc_time.y`

so aggregated sum for spent 984 for 2 months, and aggregated sum for realpurchase_cash=25, so flag=0

each group have data up to 90 days no more.

I.E.output

i decided use sqldf solution, cause i work with sql
i do so

```
a1s <- sqldf("
select 
generated_id,
[capmaing_id.x],
[campaign_id.y],
spent,
[date],
[utc_time.y],
realpurchase_cash,
--SUM(spent) over (partition by generated_id,[capmaing_id.x],[campaign_id.y]) as sum_spent,
--SUM(realpurchase_cash)  over (partition by generated_id,[capmaing_id.x],[campaign_id.y])  as sum_realpurchase_cash
case when SUM(realpurchase_cash)  over (partition by generated_id,[capmaing_id.x],[campaign_id.y])>SUM(spent) over (partition by generated_id,[capmaing_id.x],[campaign_id.y]) then 1 else 0 end as flag
from newest3
")
```

and get the error

```
Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : near "over": syntax error
```

How to do correct?

Comment: Are not you missing a `, ` after sum_realpurchase_cash?

Comment: I don't think this question deserves to be downvoted.  The author gave reproducible input and stated the error given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the question is why an error is being given.

Until RSQLite upgrades to the latest verison of the SQLite database the windowing will not work.  Instead use the RPostgreSQL backend.  With that backend use `"..."` rather than `[...]` and also fix the spelling and other errors in the sql statement shown in the question.

The gives no syntax errors (assuming the PostgreSQL server is installed and running).

```
library(sqldf)
library(RPostgreSQL)

a1s <- sqldf('
SELECT
   "generated_id",
   "campaign_id.x",
   "campaign_id.y",
   "spent",
   "date",
   "utc_time.y",
   "realpurchase_cash",
   --SUM(spent) over (partition by generated_id,[campaign_id.x],[campaign_id.y]) as sum_spent,
   --SUM(realpurchase_cash)  over (partition by generated_id,[campaign_id.x],[campaign_id.y])  as sum_realpurchase_cash
   CASE WHEN SUM("realpurchase_cash") OVER 
         (PARTITION BY "generated_id", "campaign_id.x", "campaign_id.y") > 
         SUM(spent) OVER (PARTITION BY "generated_id", "campaign_id.x", "campaign_id.y") 
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 
   END AS "flag" 
FROM "mydata"')
```

giving:

```
> a1s
   generated_id campaign_id.x campaign_id.y spent       date       utc_time.y realpurchase_cash flag
1  1.003477e+15  2.384307e+16  2.384307e+16 73.50 04.10.2018 07.10.2018 15:55              1.49    0
2  1.003477e+15  2.384307e+16  2.384307e+16 73.50 04.10.2018 30.09.2018 12:00              1.49    0
3  1.003477e+15  2.384307e+16  2.384307e+16 73.50 04.10.2018 05.10.2018 22:34              1.49    0
4  1.003477e+15  2.384307e+16  2.384307e+16 73.50 04.10.2018 01.10.2018 22:26              1.49    0
5  1.003477e+15  2.384307e+16  2.384307e+16 73.50 04.10.2018 06.10.2018 13:43              1.49    0
6  1.003477e+15  2.384307e+16  2.384307e+16 73.50 04.10.2018 06.10.2018 13:43              1.49    0
7  1.003477e+15  2.384307e+16  2.384307e+16 73.50 04.10.2018 30.09.2018 12:23              1.49    0
8  1.003477e+15  2.384307e+16  2.384307e+16 73.50 04.10.2018 30.09.2018 18:12              1.49    0
9  1.003477e+15  2.384307e+16  2.384307e+16 73.50 04.10.2018 30.09.2018 11:22              1.49    0
10 1.003477e+15  2.384307e+16  2.384307e+16 73.50 04.10.2018 05.10.2018 22:35              1.49    0
11 1.003477e+15  2.384307e+16  2.384307e+16 73.50 04.10.2018 30.09.2018 11:23              1.49    0
12 1.003477e+15  2.384307e+16  2.384307e+16 29.74 26.09.2018 07.10.2018 15:55              1.49    0
13 1.003477e+15  2.384307e+16  2.384307e+16 29.74 26.09.2018 30.09.2018 12:00              1.49    0
14 1.003477e+15  2.384307e+16  2.384307e+16 29.74 26.09.2018 05.10.2018 22:34              1.49    0
15 1.003477e+15  2.384307e+16  2.384307e+16 29.74 26.09.2018 01.10.2018 22:26              1.49    0
16 1.003477e+15  2.384307e+16  2.384307e+16 29.74 26.09.2018 06.10.2018 13:43              1.49    0
17 1.003477e+15  2.384307e+16  2.384307e+16 29.74 26.09.2018 06.10.2018 13:43              1.49    0
```